# How to extract first digit of every value of a column of dataframe(df) to a new dataframe (df1)

Tags: pandas

sample dataframe(df) having a column price as:

```
 price
0 2500
1 2600
2 5400
3 3250
4 6245
.   .
.   .
```

How to achieve df1 as:

```
 price
0  2
1  2
2  5
3  3
4  6
.  .
```

I have an idea of converting each number to string and get index(0) of each column but is there any other approach to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to strings and seelct first value:

```
df['new'] = df['price'].astype(str).str[0].astype(int)
print (df)
   price new
0   2500   2
1   2600   2
2   5400   5
3   3250   3
4   6245   6
```

Or use integer division:

```
df['new'] = df['price'] // 1000
```

Or generally:

```
print (df)
    price
0      20
1     260
2       5
3  325000
4    6245


df['new'] = df['price'] // (10 ** (np.log10(df['price'])).astype(int))
print (df)
    price  new
0      20    2
1     260    2
2       5    5
3  325000    3
4    6245    6
```

Comment: To append to existing dataframe should i have to use axis=1?

Comment: just `divmod(df.price,1000)[0]` ;)

Comment: Did I ask a duplicate question? I was given down for my question

Comment: I had an idea but unable to implement so i didn't put the code, now i got it mate thanks!!

Comment: @anky_91 It works only for multiples of 1000 right?

Comment: @Codenewbie - yes, exactly. for general solution use last one

Comment: yep, The last solution was effective but I got this error mate----AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'log10'

Comment: @Codenewbie - What is your pandas version?

Comment: pandas==0.24.2, this doesn't support?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197536/discussion-between-codenewbie-and-jezrael).